# How to get median in Scala Spark, when there's frequency of values given?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm pretty new to Spark and Scala.

Given table "tab" (but without median column):

| movie | voted_10 | voted_9 | voted_8 | median |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Some | 10 | 15 | 15 | 9 |
| Movie | 20 | 16 | 52 | 8 |

How do you calculate the median column?
The voted_* columns are frequencies of ratings 10-1 (the values mean how many people rated the movie 10, how many rated it 9 etc.).

I calculated the mean like this:

```
val ratingsDfChanged = ratingsDf
  .withColumn("mean", ((col("votes_1")+col("votes_2")*2+col("votes_3")*3+col("votes_4")*4+col("votes_5")*5+col("votes_6")*6+col("votes_7")*7+col("votes_8")*8+col("votes_9")*9+col("votes_10")*10)/$"total_votes")) // :))
```

Which doesn't look pretty, but in the case of median I have no idea how to do it.

I've tried something like

```
.withColumn("wartosci", Array.fill($"votes_10")(10))
```

And then maybe concatenate these arrays and finally calculate median, but in this case I get error, because Array.fill requires int and I'm passing in column, if you know how to bypass that it would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid hardcoding the score columns, apply a pattern filtering to capture the column names, sort the column names by their corresponding scores, and assemble a Map with the column names and corresponding scores as keys/values.

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Forrest Gump", 10, 15, 15),
  ("The Matrix", 20, 16, 52)
).toDF("movie", "scored_10", "scored_9", "scored_8")

val scoreSorted = df.columns.
  filter(_.matches("scored_\\d+")).
  sortBy(_.split("_")(1).toInt)  // sorted for computing median
// Array(scored_8, scored_9, scored_10)

val scoreMap = scoreSorted.map(c => (c, c.split("_")(1).toInt)).toMap
```

For the `mean`, use `foldLeft` to aggregate for the total scores to be divided by the total votes:

```
df.
  withColumn("votes", scoreSorted.map(col).reduce(_ + _)).
  withColumn("mean", scoreSorted.foldLeft(lit(0.0))((acc, c) =>
    acc + col(c) * scoreMap(c)) / $"votes"
  ).
show
// +------------+---------+--------+--------+-----+-----------------+
// |       movie|scored_10|scored_9|scored_8|votes|             mean|
// +------------+---------+--------+--------+-----+-----------------+
// |Forrest Gump|       10|      15|      15|   40|            8.875|
// |  The Matrix|       20|      16|      52|   88|8.636363636363637|
// +------------+---------+--------+--------+-----+-----------------+
```

To compute the `median`, first generate data row-wise via [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#explode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) from an array composed of elements expanded out of the `scoreMap`, followed by using [`percentile_approx`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#percentile_approx(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,percentage:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,accuracy:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) with `percentage` set to 0.5 (i.e. mid point) and `accuracy` set to maximum:

```
df.
  withColumn("scores", explode(flatten(array(scoreSorted.map(c =>
    array_repeat(lit(scoreMap(c)), col(c))): _*)
  ))).
  groupBy("movie").agg(
    percentile_approx($"scores", lit(0.5), lit(Int.MaxValue)).as("median")
  ).
show
// +------------+------+
// |       movie|median|
// +------------+------+
// |Forrest Gump|     9|
// |  The Matrix|     8|
// +------------+------+
```

Note that `percentile_approx` is available only on Spark `3.1`+.  Its `accuracy` parameter takes an integer between `1` and `Int` max value -- the higher the value the more accurate (and more costly) is the percentile result.  Also note that the sorting of the score columns is for computing `median` (i.e. not needed for computing `mean`) and doing it upfront costs less.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that in spark, you can manipulate your list of columns and perform operations on them programmatically. For the mean, you can sum all the columns starting with `voted`, and then divide by the number of such columns:

```scala
val vote_cols = df.columns.filter(_ startsWith "voted")
val result = df.withColumn("mean", vote_cols.map(col).reduce( _ + _) / vote_cols.size)
```

For the median it is a bit more complicated in pure spark but totally feasible. You can put all the columns into an array, sort that array and then 2 possibilities. Either the number of columns if odd, in that case you take the middle value. Either it is even, in that case you take the mean of the two middle values:

```scala
val median =
  if(vote_cols.size % 2 == 1)
      element_at('votes, vote_cols.size/2 + 1)
  else (
      element_at('votes, vote_cols.size/2) + 
      element_at('votes, vote_cols.size/2 + 1)
       ) / 2

val result = df
    .withColumn("votes", array_sort(array(vote_cols.map(col) : _*)))
    .withColumn("median", median)
```